# Thread Error for Custom UITableView

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, uitableview

I am trying to follow this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-customize-uitableview-storyboard/

So far as I can tell, I've built the project in the exact same way as instructed, but when trying to run it, I get a thread error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-  
[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the 
"2-view-3" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
 *** First throw call stack:
(0x1c91012 0x10cee7e 0x1c90deb 0x242357 0xf3ff8 0xf4232 0x433d5 0x4376f 0x43905 0x4c917    
0x1096c 0x1194b 0x22cb5 0x23beb 0x15698 0x1becdf9 0x1becad0 0x1c06bf5 0x1c06962 
0x1c37bb6 0x1c36f44 0x1c36e1b 0x1117a 0x12ffc 0x211d 0x2045)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

From what I can tell online, the error comes up with the table view isn't properly linked. The dataSource and delegate connections on my table view are linked up to the View Controller. Is there any other place I should be looking? Thanks to anyone who can help!

ViewController.h file:
    #import

```
@interface ViewController : UITableViewController<UITableViewDelegate,   
UITableViewDataSource>

@end
```

ViewController.m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "BookCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
NSArray *books;
}

- (void)loadView {
[super loadView];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.navigationItem.title = @"List of Books";
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"   
style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];

BookCell *book1 =[BookCell new];
book1.bookTitle = @"Pride and Prejudice";
book1.dateAdded = @"March 14th, 2013";
book1.imageFile = @"pridepreduciezombie.jpg";

BookCell *book2 = [BookCell new];
book2.bookTitle = @"Objective C for Dummies";
book2.dateAdded = @"January 5th, 2014";
book2.imageFile = @"object_c_dummy.jpg";


books = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:book1, book2, nil];


// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return books.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// Configure the cell...
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Display recipe in the table cell
BookCell *book = [books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIImageView *bookImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
bookImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:book.imageFile];

UILabel *bookTitle = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
bookTitle.text = book.bookTitle;

UILabel *dateAdded = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
dateAdded.text = book.dateAdded;

return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using a storyboard and not a nib file?

Comment: I think so. How could I double check that?

Comment: Look at the name of the file you are building the interface in. It should be called "file_name.storyboard", not "file_name.xib". The third line of your error says that it loaded a nib file name "2-view-3", which doesn't sound like a storyboard.

Comment: MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard. I don't see any xib files. 

Should the BookCell.h and BookCell.m have a subclass of UITableViewCell or UIViewController? Would that have anything to do with it?

Comment: @Mownier How would I do that? Under viewDidLoad, I tried self.view=[[BookCell alloc] init], but it returned an error about pointers.

Comment: Did you set in IB the custom class of the controller as ViewController? I think the controller in the storyboard is an instance of UIViewController. Instead drag a UITableViewController and set that as your initial view controller. Then, set the custom class as ViewController. By the way in your code, omit the <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>.

Comment: In the right side panel of IB, select the 'Identity Inspector' tab. You will see a 'Custom Class' section and from there set the custom class of the UITableViewController as ViewController. Omit the overridden method loadView since you're not doing any customization stuffs within the method.

Comment: My view controller in the storyboard is set to a "custom class" of UIViewController. My view is just set to View, and my Table View (UITableView) won't let me change the class. Am I still looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1):

Remove this code from .h file `<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>`because your `viewcontrolller` is sub class of `UITableViewController so no need to use`Delegate`and`dataSource`of`UITableViewController`.

Now Just simply replace this code of .h file

```
@interface ViewController : UITableViewController<UITableViewDelegate,   
UITableViewDataSource>

@end
```

with this one

```
@interface ViewController : UITableViewController
@end
```

Comment: @Michelle can you please give me your code then I will be able to identify the problem correctly, because your given information is not sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Since You are using the `Deleguates` already then you could just subclass from `UIViewController`:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,
                                                           UITableViewDataSource>
```